# SQL order by sum column, when tie need to set order by subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a SQL Server 2008 query that groups a calculated column "points". When the "points" tie I need to look to another field to determine the correct order.

```
SELECT     
    p.DriverID, 
    p.DriverName, 
    p.CarNum, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.RaceType = 10 THEN (200 - ((p.CarPosition - 1) * 2)) ELSE 0 END) AS Points
FROM
    RaceParticipants AS p 
    INNER JOIN Race AS r ON p.RaceID = r.RaceID
GROUP BY 
    r.RaceDateID, p.DriverID, p.DriverName, p.CarNum
HAVING
    (r.RaceDateID IN (255, 256))
ORDER BY 
    Points DESC
```

The column I would need to look to would be `p.CarPosition WHERE r.RaceType = 60`
so it would have to be some sort of sub query?

Comment: Can you add that extra case statement as a column in your query and then include it in the ORDER BY clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT DriverID, DriverName,CarNum,Points
FROM (SELECT     
           p.DriverID, 
           p.DriverName, 
           p.CarNum, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN r.RaceType = 10 THEN (200 - ((p.CarPosition - 1) * 2)) ELSE 0 END) AS Points,
           MAX(CASE WHEN r.RaceType = 60 THEN p.CarPosition ELSE 999999 END) AS OrderField
      FROM
           RaceParticipants AS p 
           INNER JOIN Race AS r ON p.RaceID = r.RaceID
      WHERE r.RaceDateID IN (255, 256)
      GROUP BY 
           r.RaceDateID, p.DriverID, p.DriverName, p.CarNum
   )sub
ORDER BY 
    Points DESC, OrderField
```

Depending on how you want the 2nd order field to be handled you can alter the `ELSE`, with no `ELSE` you'd return `NULL` which sorted ascending comes before other values.